# Possible to get mouse events fired when cursor is outside page?

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a game in which one can hold the mouse button and drag it around to rotate an object. However, when the mouse position is outside the page bounds, all mouse events are not fired anymore. This means that the object isn't rotated anymore when the cursor is outside the page; moreover, when the user releases the mouse outside the page bounds, I cannot keep track of that which means the object is still being rotated when the cursor gets back in the page bounds, although it isn't pressed anymore.

So, is there any way to make mousemove / mousedown / mouse[...] events get fired when the cursor is outside the page bounds?

Comment: I think if this exist, it will act very different in different browsers and OS.

Comment: Why would it act so differently? It's not that complex in my honest opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. But you can track mouseout events and make them act like mouseup.

Comment: That solves the second problem, but not the first. It may be worth implementing though

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not, sorry about that!

Comment: Oh well, than it's just a pity. No need to be sorry :)

Answer (score 1):

ya that doesn't make sense that you would be able to anyway.  If you're not interacting with the browser, then how does the browser know what to do?

Comment: Well, if one pressed the mouse button and rotates the object around, it would make sense if he can move the cursor all around the screen and that the object doesn't stop rotating when the cursor is outside the page. Not very user-friendly.

Comment: yes, i know what you mean.  I guess one thing you can check for then is where the mouse is and check to see if it goes beyond bounds of the window itself.

Comment: As far as I know it is not just possible to see the position of the cursor on the screen when it is outside the window. In fact, if that was possible, there wouldn't be any problems at all;)

Comment: right, but you can track to see where the mouse is inside the window itself.  you can have some listener that looks for the mouse location inside the window and if it ever reaches the window's bounds, then you can fire off some event

Answer (score 1):

You can use mouseleave, which works in jQuery 1.4.

In JQuery:

```
$("body").mouseleave(function() {
    //Your code here
    alert("Mouse has left");
});
```

This does work in Firefox and IE7 from my testing.

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1805-jQuery-Events-MouseOver-MouseOut-vs-MouseEnter-MouseLeave.htm

Comment: Thanks, but then when the mouse is moving outside the page, there is no way to see where it goes, is there?

Comment: Ah, no there isn't. Sorry for the half answer on that.