# Is there a KeyUp event when a key is released outside the page?

Tags: javascript

I can currently see which keys are pressed using JavaScript, using a library that relies on `KeyDown` / `KeyUp` events. Although this works beautifully when keys are pressed/released inside the page, the events do not fire when a key is released outside the page (i.e., when it does not have focus).

So, one could press the `Enter` key when the page has focus (the event will fire, everything goes well), but when he releases it when the page does not have focus, the event does *not* fire, which results in an unability for me to know whether the key is still pressed or not.

As for the library used, please refer to:
http://www.n-son.com/scripts/keyLib/keyLib.js

Is it possible to know when a key is released when the page does not have focus? Or is there perhaps a general function to check if a key is pressed at a specific time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would reset all your this-key-is-down flags to `false` when the window loses focus, which you can do using `window`'s `blur` event:

```
var someKeyIsDown;

window.onblur = function() {
    someKeyIsDown = false;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

If they're not interacting with 'your' program (in the case of a web page, 'your' program is a part of their web browser) then anything they do won't generate events that your program knows about.

Allowing a web page to know about events that have nothing to do with it (such as me typing a confidential e-mail in a totally separate program, or entering a password, or anything else) would be a huge security risk.

Comment: Good point, I hadn't thought about that. It would be a bad idea to have on-line keyloggers...

Answer (score 1):

can't you use higher levels events such as KeyPressed , which garantee that the key were hit down then released  ?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm using it in a game. Therefore, functions need to be called as long as a key is pressed, so it is not just a press/release case.

Comment: You can't capture events occuring outside your window. The best you can do is listen to focus/blur events and consider them as if they were KeyUp events. this is comparable to what you asked there about mouse events: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748177/possible-to-get-mouse-events-fired-when-cursor-is-outside-page

Comment: Yes that's reasonable, thanks. And indeed I did ask it as for the mouse already, but perhaps there would be a solution for keys.